# Problems fitting a video background with css grid

Tags: php, html, css, video, grid

new here at every aspect xd Sry for my bad english.
Im trying to make a typical "background" video at my page but i can't to make the video fit the content of the grid cell whatever I do.

The idea is that the video stay at z-index -1 and fit 1920x1080px but for some reason it got resized and stay at the center o do crazy things.

The first I do its a grid template with divs, and I make the first of them 1920x1080px, 2 columns.
Then this happens when I put in the video on that cell (video is 1920x1080px):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDr9Q.jpg)

I tried putting video with pos: absolute, I tried with the container too, assigning height, widths, justify-content, top:0, display: block ... i have no clues now, ive tried almost everything that I knew and googled but I couldnt do do the shit.

Heres my html:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="main-container">

        <div class="item1">1
            <video id="vid" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone-child/img/coffee1.mp4" width="1920" height="1080" autoplay loop muted type="video/mp4"> </video>
        </div> 
        <div class="item2">2</div>
        <div class="item3">3</div>
        <div class="item4">4</div>
        <div class="item5">5</div>      
        <div class="item6">6</div>
        <div class="item7">7</div>
        <div class="item8">8</div>
        <div class="item9">9</div>
        <div class="item10">10</div>
        
        
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And my css

```
/*GRID index*/
.main-container {
    
    display:grid;
    background-color: red;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  
}
.main-container div {
    color:black;
    border: 1px solid black;
     
}
.main-container video {
    display:block;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    
}

.item1{
    
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    background-color: green;
    height:1080px;

}
```

Can u help me? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Ty for answer! And nope. Ive just put absolute on video now. But when i try f12 and make the responsive, the video goes to center and the margin top keeps growing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `object-fit` and `object-position` to scale and position the video.
Even if the element is 1920x1080 the video contents may not depending on the videos aspect ratio and by default get scaled to be contained in the element.

```css
/*GRID index*/
.main-container {
    
    display:grid;
    background-color: red;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  
}
.main-container div {
    color:black;
    border: 1px solid black;
     
}
.main-container video {
    display:block;

    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    
    /* Scale video to container size */
   object-fit: cover;
   object-position: center;
    
}

.item1{
    
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    background-color: green;
    height:1080px;

}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">

        <div class="item1">
            <video id="vid" src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4" width="1920" height="1080" autoplay loop muted type="video/mp4"> </video>
        </div> 
        <div class="item2">2</div>
        <div class="item3">3</div>
        <div class="item4">4</div>
        <div class="item5">5</div>      
        <div class="item6">6</div>
        <div class="item7">7</div>
        <div class="item8">8</div>
        <div class="item9">9</div>
        <div class="item10">10</div>
        
        
        </div>
```

Comment: Nice thank you, ive tried the object-fit but not the object-position. Now have a nice beahviour at responsive but i have a margin-top with the video like 20px now :/.p.d YEAH ITS DONE TY BRO I LOVE U. The "margin" was the "1" at html div. TY SO MUCH

Comment: object-position is to center the video, otherwise you would only see top-left corner which most likely is not the focus. Also note that the video has to have `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` for it to work.

Comment: I will remember that I assure you haha i spend like 4 hours trying. Truly ty

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCFPG.jpg)

Heres the inspector with this css:

```
/*GRID index*/
```

.main-container {

```
display:grid;
background-color: red;
grid-template-columns: auto auto;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

}
.main-container div {

```
color:black;
border: 1px solid black;
```

}
.main-container video {

```
position:absolute;
align-self:stretch;
justify-self:stretch;
display:block;
top:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
min-height:400px;
min-width:400px;
```

}